# Give infinity sequence S a generic strategy to proof S is convergent or divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Give an infinity sequence S, what strategy to proof S is convergent or divergent in a generic form for many sequences.

Example for doubt:

Give the sequence 
$$S=(0, \frac{1}{27},\frac{2}{81},..., \frac{n - 1}{3^{(n+1)}},... )$$ for $n=1,2,...$

> > > > Edited----------------Start
> > > >         $$ \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{i-1}{3^{i+1}} $$
> > > >         Edited----------------End.

How to proof the sequence.

In the way, I think the Cauchy convergence criterion method is sufficient to solve and to proof in generic form if a sequence is convergent or divergent. Or use other way like Dirichlet's method to test convergence.
What strategy I must use?

Comment: Sequence or  series $\sum_1^\infty \frac{n-1}{3^{n+1}}$?

Comment: Yes. Series sum.

Comment: For series with positive terms, the general strategy is to show that the terms go to $0$ "fast enough." Implementation details are series dependent, though after one has picked up some experience most series give no trouble.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks.